# What's the difference of economic capital and liquidity buffer?

Tags: banking, capital, liquidity

Economic capital is what for example a bank has and uses in order to stay solvent. Isn't this in a way a liquidity buffer? or what would be the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different sides of the balance sheet.

- Capital represents long-dated instruments (infinite lifetime in the case of common equity) issued by a bank that are subordinated in a way to make them comparable to equity. (Can include instruments that are technically liabilities.) The existence of capital means that assets are greater than non-capital liabilities, i.e., the bank remains solvent.
- A liquidity buffer are assets that are deemed liquid, which means that they can be readily sold at prices near carrying value to meet payment requirements. Note that a solvent entity that only holds hard-to-liquidate assets may be unable to meet a sudden payment obligation. That is, it is solvent, but illiquid.

Comment: - What happens if a bank is solvent yet illiquid? Would they have to use the illiquid asset as collateral and take a loan on that?

Comment: They would  need to go to the central bank to be bailed out. If something is illiquid, you can’t easily borrow against it.